# Is there a way to set JAVA_HOME automatically?

Tags: xubuntu

I actually installed Java following the instructions of this answer: [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/q/56104/447519)

When I did

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

The response was empty, so I googled a bit and followed the advice of this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/24641536/2003898

finally everything worked and I was able to start the build script I had to set up....

except the fact, that it responded:

> Your java version is greater than JDK 1.7. Cannot start FOobAR

"Well so set up another version and done", one might say now, but my problem is, I'm working with another project that REQUIRES Java to be at least 1.8

So is there a way of setting up java that updates the JAVA_HOME path and does all the other stuff I might not even be aware of, automatically? Or do I have to change all this configs multiple times a day manually?

Comment: did you try adding `export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/your/desired/jdk` in the script that starts your other project? Its that simple really.

Comment: @PrahladYeri: I'm having high temprature and can't access the machine, but mind putting it in as answer? This might realy allready solve the problem. So even can't accept it yet, but would be fair.